# inseting values into sql using pymysql using formated table name

Tags: python, mysql, sql-server, formatting, pymysql

i came across two instances first one

```
 n=("""INSERT INTO table_name (name,other) values(%s,%s)""")
    cur.execute(n,(c1,c3,))
```

well this worked perfect but where as

```
n=("""INSERT INTO %s (name,other) values(%s,%s)""")
cur.execute(n,(table_name,c1,c3,))
```

this failed to insert values

the table name is taken as input by the user

this is error that i got

```
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''elon_musk' (name,other) values('Elon Musk','Musk in 2015')' at line 1")
```

Comment: You cannot parameterize the table name. You'll need to use `format()` to put the table name in the string. You're responsible for sanitizing the input.

Comment: can u please suggest a code thank you

Comment: `c.execute("""INSERT INTO {} (name,other) values(%s,%s)""".format(table_name), (c1, c3))`

Comment: thanks that worked